# Postgres - How do I check for the date a specific field in a row has been last modified?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a table called `invoices` which has a column `status`. For invoice with ID of 10, I need to know when its status has been last updated.

Comment: provide some sample data

Comment: It's not possible, unless you have specific time_updated column in your table, and your application is updating this column when status changes.

Comment: @mvp I do have an `updated_at` column but it returns the date for which the entire row has been updated

Comment: Perhaps you should create new field status_updated_at, and maintain it in your app. But it won't help for existing data set.

Comment: Unless you have a column that stores that information, there is no way you can get that information.

Comment: Is the change of `status` the only thing you need to track? If not, you're better off with some form of auditing / generic data change tracking (e.g. [trigger audit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-AUDIT-EXAMPLE))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to write 'before update' trigger and compare both values, existing in table and to be inserted. If the values differ, make an insert in log table(if you have it) and then update the master table with new values.